# thymeleaf - Spring boot - validação Vazio

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Tenho esse código que já funciona:

```
<span class="label" th:classappend="${usuario.ativo ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger'}"> </span></td>
```

porém agora eu quero o seguinte:

```
    <span class="label" th:classappend="${usuario == vazio ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger'}"> </span></td>
```

se o usuário for igual a vazio o label vai ficar label-danger

porém não funcionou pelo fato de estar errado ... alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: ${#strings.isEmpty(name)} 

achei a resposta 


link: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi com: ${#strings.isEmpty(name)}

achei a resposta no link: 
http://thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings

Answer (score 0):

Tente a modificação abaixo. Se for somente isto, ok. Caso contrário, precisa adicionar mais informações na pergunta, amigo.

```
 <span class="label" th:classappend="${usuario == null ? 'label-success' : 'label-danger'}"> </span></td>
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda. Resolvi com:
${#strings.isEmpty(name)}

Comment: @JoyceSD, já que conseguiu resolver, forneça uma resposta para a sua própria pergunta :)